# Difference between BRIN index and table partitioning in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

What is the difference between a BRIN index and a table partition in PostgreSQL? When I should use one instead of another? It seems that they provide very similar benefits and also have similar use cases

*Example*

Suppose we have the following table structure

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
store_id INT,
client_id INT,
created_at timestamp,
information jsonb
)
```

that has the following characteristics:

- orders can only be inserted, deletions are not allowed and updates are very rare and they don't involve the *created_at* column
- the *created_at* column contains the timestamp of the insertion of the row in the database thus the values in the column are strictly increasing
- almost every query use the *created_at* column in a condition and some of them may use the *store_id* and *client_id* columns
- the most accessed rows are the most recent ones in terms of the *created_at* column
- some queries may return a few records (example: analyzing a single record or the records created in a small time interval) while others may scan a vast amount of records (example: aggregate functions for a dashboard functionality)

I have chosen this example because it's very common and also both approach could be used (in my opinion). In this case which choice should I use between a BRIN index on the whole table or a partitioned table with maybe a btree index (or just a simple btree index without partitioning)? Does the table dimension influence the choice?

Comment: What (performance) problem do you have? And could you show us the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for the SELECT statements where this problem occurs? I do use table partitioning for tables that receive hundreds of millions records a month, brin is something I never used. But without a problem, there is nothing to solve.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I don't have an actual problem. I would like to know the differences between the two approach since they can be used in similar situations and provide the same benefits. I also made an example for clarification, but it was just a theoretical example

Comment: Without a real example, there is not much you can do. As far as I know, there is a huge difference between the two, but I've never used brin. Without knowing the number of records and the actual queries, I would not spend time on hypothetical optimisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used both features (although I'll caveat that my experience with partitioning is from back when you had to use inheritance + constraints, before the introduction of CREATE TABLE ... PARTITION BY). You are correct that they seem similar-ish on a surface level, but they function by completely different mechanisms.

Table partitioning basically works as follows: replace all references to `table` with `(select * from table_partition1 union all select * from table_partition2 /* repeat for all partitions */)`. The partitions will have a constraint on the partition columns, so that if those columns appear in a WHERE, the constraints can be applied up-front to prune which partitions are actually scanned. IOW, if table_partition1 has `CHECK(client_id=1)`, and your WHERE Has `client_id=2`, table_partition1 will be skipped since the table constraint automatically excludes all rows from this partition from passing that WHERE.

BRIN indexes, in contrast, choose a block size for the table, and then for each block, records a min/max bound of the indexed column. This allows WHERE conditions to skip entire blocks when we can see, say, that the maximum created_at in a particular block of rows is below a `created_at>={some_value}`  clause in your WHERE.

I can't tell you a definitive answer for your case as to which would work better. Well, that's not true, actually: the definitive answer is, "benchmark it for your own data" ;)

This is kind of fuzzy, but my general feeling is that BRIN is lightweight, and table partitioning is not. BRIN is something that can be added on to an existing table without much trouble, the indexes themselves are very small, and the impact on writes is not major (at least, not without inordinately many indices). Table partitioning, on the other hand, is a different way of representing the data on-disk; you are actually determining into which data files particular rows will be written. This requires a much more involved migration process when introducing it to an existing dataset.

However, the set of query optimizations available for table partitioning is much greater. Not only is there the constraint exclusion I described above, but you can *also* have indices (even BRIN ones!) on each individual partition. Of course, you can also have BRIN + other indices on a single-big-table, but I'm not sure that is particularly helpful IRL.

A few other thoughts: BRIN is good for monotonic data (timestamps, incremnting IDs, etc); the more correlated the on-disk ordering is to the indexed value, the more effective a BRIN index can be at pruning blocks to be scanned. Things like customer IDs, however, are unlikely to work well with BRIN; any given block of rows is likely to have at least one relatively low and relatively high ID. However, fields that like work quite well for partitioning: a partition-per-client, or partitioning on the modulus of a customer ID (which would more commonly be called sharding), is a good way of scaling horizontally, almost without bound.

Answer (score 1):

Any update, even if it does not change the indexed column, will make a BRIN index pretty useless (unless it is a HOT update). Even without that, there are differences, for example:

- partitioning allows you to get rid of lots of data efficiently, a BRIN index won't
- a partitioned table allows one autovacuum worker per partition, which improves autovacuum performance

But if your only concern is to efficiently select all rows for a certain value of the index or partitioning key, both may offer about the same benefit.